# :greater_than_or_equal_to in validates_numericality_of only partially working in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

We are using the following to check if stock_qty (an integer or a float. Could be zero but not nil) is greater or equal to zero:

```
validates_numericality_of :stock_qty, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
validates_numericality_of :stock_qty, :less_than_or_equal_to => :in_qty, :if => Proc.new { |part| !part.in_qty.nil? }
```

:in_qty is a column in part model. This validation should allow positive or 0 for :stock_qty. The problem is that the rspec failed if :stock_qty is assigned zero. I noticed that :less_than_or_equal_to only allowed less_than and did not allow equal_to. Is there a way to validate the >= or <= in rails 3.1? Or what may go wrong with our validation code above. Thanks so much.

Comment: The code above seems all right...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try adding `:only_integer => true` like so:

```
validates_numericality_of :stock_qty, :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
```

EDIT

if this needs to pass when stock_qty is nil or zero you need to change your code to this:

```
validates_numericality_of :stock_qty, :allow_nil => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
validates_numericality_of :stock_qty, :allow_nil => true, :less_than_or_equal_to => :in_qty, :if => Proc.new { |part| !part.in_qty.nil? }
```

Comment: Just added :stock_qty could be either integer or float. Thanks.

Comment: :only_integer => true did not change the rspec result.

Comment: Does this test need to pass if stock_qty is nil or zero?

Comment: stock_qty could be zero, but not nil.

Answer (score 12):

```
validates :stock_qty, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

it works in my 3.1 app, in my case I have price, and when I update or add the product wthout price I got the "it's not a number" error, or something like that, but I can put a 0 in price column and it updates just fine. hope this helps.

:`greater_than_or_equal_to –` Specifies the value must be greater than or equal to the supplied value. The default error message for this option is “must be greater than or equal to %{count}”.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: Tried exactly the same using validates, rspec still failed with stock_qty == 0. Thanks.

Comment: However in rails console, it is OK to save a record with 0 stock_qty. It seems that rspec failed but actual model passed. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Also you could believe that there were 0 while there were `nil`. `nil` won't pass this checking.

Comment: Did you mean zero and nil are treated the same in the validation?

Comment: No, quite the opposite: you could write something like `Model1.new.valid?` and got `false` while `stock_qty` was `nil`. That's the only explanation that comes in mind (because I hope you didn't make another validation for you model that fails an you forgot about it).

Answer (score 0):

For Rails > 6.1.0

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 validates :age, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 18, less_than_or_equal_to: 65 }
end
```

I find the answer [in this link](https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/02/05/add-validate-numericality-in-range.html)

I hope it was easy and clear